# java: to retrieve a part of a string that begins and ends with a specific string

Tags: java, string

This is the program and i have a string `strLineText` from which i need to extract the words that contain `target` in them.

Ex. In the string `"random string with IWANTTHISABC-123 and more"` i need to extract `IWANTTHISABC-123`. Similarly if the string is `"random string with IWANTTHISBBC-001"` i need to extract `IWANTTHISBBC-001. The prefix is fixed

I have tried it with `substring()` ***(Method1)*** but the logic doesn't work for Strings that end with this target word i.e., nothing is outputted

I tried the `split()` ***(Method2)*** and it works for all four combinations.

Can you help me with achieving using the `substring()` ***(Method1)*** for all four combinations

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String target = "IWANTTHIS";

    //Four possible inputs
    String strLineText = "random string with IWANTTHISABC-123 and more";   //works
    String strLineText = "IWANTTHISCBC-45601 and more";                    //works
    String strLineText = "IWANTTHISEBC-1";                                 //doesn't work
    String strLineText = "random string with IWANTTHISKBC-55545";          //doesn't work

    //Method1
    System.out.println("O/P 1:" + strLineText.substring(strLineText.indexOf(target), 
            strLineText.indexOf(target) + strLineText.substring(strLineText.indexOf(target)).indexOf(" ") + 1).trim());

    //Method2
    for (String s : strLineText.split(" "))
        if (s.contains(target))
            System.out.println("O/P 2:" + s.trim());
}
```

Comment: In order to use `substring` you need to know begin and end index to get the exact part from string

Comment: What's the criteria for the "word" you're trying to extract? For the string "random string with IWANTTHISABC-123 and more" you want "IWANTTHISABC", correct? Meaning find me any contiguous sequence of alpha characters containing the target? And does the string ever have alpha characters in front of "IWANTTHIS"? Like "FOOBARIWANTTHISXYZ"?

Comment: Can you rigorously describe the string you want to find? If so, then use java.util.regex package to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

`strLineText.substring(strLineText.indexOf(target)).indexOf(" ")` will be -1 if `strLineText` contains no spaces after your target string. You could check if `strLineText.substring(strLineText.indexOf(target))` contains spaces, and if not, take the substring until the end of `strLineText`:

```java
//Method1
int beginIndex = strLineText.indexOf(target);
String substring = strLineText.substring(beginIndex);
int endIndex = substring.contains(" ") ? beginIndex + substring.indexOf(" ") : strLineText.length();
System.out.println("O/P 1:" + strLineText.substring(beginIndex, endIndex));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty straightforward, you just need to compute the end index starting from begin index. Here is the snippet that works for all cases.

```
int begin = strLineText.indexOf(target);
int end = strLineText.indexOf(" ", begin);
if(end == -1) end = strLineText.length();

System.out.println(strLineText.substring(begin, end));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes that your definition of "word" is a sequence of alphas, excluding numbers, symbols, etc. For other definitions of "word," the regular expression can be adjusted accordingly. If you want to include parts of the word previous to the target string, you can add a loop that counts backwards from startIndex, examining characters to see if they are alpha.

```
public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String target = "IWANTTHIS";

//    String candidate = "random string with IWANTTHISABC-123 and more";
      String candidate = "IWANTTHISCBC-45601 and more";
//    String candidate = "IWANTTHISEBC-1";
//    String candidate = "random string with IWANTTHISKBC-55545";

    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;

    if(candidate.contains(target))
    {
      System.out.println("Target located.");

      startIndex = candidate.indexOf(target);

      System.out.println("target starts at " + startIndex);

      // keep adding characters until first non-alpha char

      endIndex = startIndex + target.length();

      boolean wordEnded = false;

      while(!wordEnded && (endIndex >= candidate.length()))
      {
        String foo = Character.toString(candidate.charAt(endIndex + 1));

        if(foo.matches("[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
          endIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
          wordEnded = true;
        }
      }

      String full = candidate.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);

      System.out.println("Full string = " + full);
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("No target located. Exiting.");
    }
  }
}
```